# How to make button enable/disable based on [sortablejs]

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

I have a list which has Drag and Drop feature

```
<div   [sortablejs]="actionList"> 

<div *ngFor="let data of actionList | filterBy: searchValue;let i = index">
```

And a button like below

```
<button  (click)="save()">  Save</button>
```

How to make this button enable only when drag and drop is made by user
Here I am using **SortablejsModule** for drag and drop feature for the list

Comment: get the drag and drop event if its is success, create global variable set false initially and after get success event it is true. and use on buttton `[disabled]="variable_name"`

Comment: My concern is on how to get that drag and drop event,can you please let me know that

Comment: @Abhishek  My concern is on how to get that drag and drop event,can you please let me know that

Comment: can you provide me minimal `https://stackblitz.com/` ?

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs#tracking-lists-update-events then set `[sortablejsOptions]="options"` on your outer div and proceed with the idea from @Abhishek

Comment: @Shiny check it if any help for you [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2bmry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can drageableOption as params like this and attach a function when drag and drop event happen.

in your `html`

```
<div   [sortablejs]="actionList" [sortablejsOptions]="draggableOptions"> 

<div *ngFor="let data of actionList | filterBy: searchValue;let i = index">
```

and in your `.ts`

> import { SortablejsOptions } from 'angular-sortablejs';

```
export class StockMovementComponent implements OnInit{

disableButton: boolean = true;

draggableOptions : SortablejsOptions = {
    animation: 150,
    onUpdate: () => this.dragDropDataSuccess(),
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100
  };

constructor(){}

ngOnInit() {}

dragDropDataSuccess(){
this.disableButton = false;
}

}
```